# Oracle nested query reference parent column more than 1 level deep

Tags: oracle, nested, subquery

I know that the oracle limitation for nested query with reference parent more than 1 level deep requires us to show some creativity but I'm really stuck on this one.

I need to create a view by selecting the field of a table named "PROGRAM" containing tv program and including in the view a field named "PRODUCERS" that has to be the concatenation of all the producers involved in the tv program.

Therefore I'm eventually dealing with 3 tables during the view creation:

PROGRAM (id_program, director,...)

PRODUCER (id_producer, name, ...)

PROGRAM_PRODUCER (id_producer, id_program)

Here is the query to create the view:

```
DROP VIEW VIEW_PROGRAM;

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VIEW_PROGRAM
(
   PRGM_ID,
   FORMAT_TITLE,
   GENRE,
   TYPE,
   DIRECTOR,
   ORIGIN1,
   PRODUCER,
   BROADCAST_TIME,
   DURATION,
   CHANNEL,
   LOCAL_TITLE
)
AS
   SELECT program.id_program AS prgm_id,
          program.original_title AS format_title,
          genres.genre AS genre,
          genres.type_ AS TYPE,
          program.director AS director,
          program.origin1,

          (Select listagg(producer,' / ') WITHIN GROUP (order by 'producer') 
          FROM  (SELECT P.PRODUCER FROM PRODUCERS P WHERE P.ID IN 
          (SELECT PP.ID_PRODUCER FROM PROGRAM_PRODUCER PP WHERE PP.ID_PROGRAM = 19927))) AS producer,

          program.broadcast_time AS broadcast_time,
          program.duration AS duration,
          channels.channel AS channel,
          program.local_title
     FROM program
          LEFT JOIN genres
             ON program.p_genre = genres.id_genre
          LEFT JOIN countries
             ON program.p_country = countries.id_country
          LEFT JOIN channels
             ON program.p_channel = channels.id_channel;
```

My problem is with the part:

```
          (Select listagg(producer,' / ') WITHIN GROUP (order by 'producer') 
          FROM  (SELECT P.PRODUCER FROM PRODUCERS P WHERE P.ID IN 
          (SELECT PP.ID_PRODUCER FROM PROGRAM_PRODUCER PP WHERE PP.ID_PROGRAM = 19927))) AS producer,
```

Except **the value "19927" should actually reference "prgm_id"**, but this will obviously throw the unknown identifier exception..

I've spent a lot of time trying to pull the where clause somewhere else but without success, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `IN` and another subquery in that section, instead of joining `producers` to `program_producer`? And why are you ordering by a constant rather than a column value - I guess that's just a mistake? I'm not sure why you have a subquery at all, and aren't joining to the fourth table in the main querying and using a `group by` clause....

Comment: Whether I use a join or a in clause it won't change the fact that my listagg function will require a nested query and therefore that the same issue will occur when referencing to prgm_id

Comment: A join would get rid of one level of nesting; you have an extra redundant level there already. You can reduce it to a single subquery, which can then see the outer query's column value; or eliminate even that subquery with extra joins and a group by in the main query.

Comment: You are right, I just didn't see it... Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the nested subqueries; you could replace that section with a join in a single level of subquery, which can still refer to program:

```
      (Select listagg(p.producer,' / ') WITHIN GROUP (order by p.producer) 
        FROM PRODUCERS P
        JOIN PROGRAM_PRODUCER PP ON P.ID_PRODUCER = PP.ID_PRODUCER
        WHERE PP.ID_PROGRAM = program.id_program) AS producer,
```

Or you could remove the subquery completely by including the extra tables in the main outer join sequence and adding a `group by` clause that includes all the other select list items:

```
   SELECT program.id_program AS prgm_id,
          program.original_title AS format_title,
          genres.genre AS genre,
          genres.type_ AS TYPE,
          program.director AS director,
          program.origin1,
          listagg(producers.producer,' / ')
            WITHIN GROUP (order by producers.producer) AS producer,
          program.broadcast_time AS broadcast_time,
          program.duration AS duration,
          channels.channel AS channel,
          program.local_title
     FROM program
          LEFT JOIN program_producer
             ON program_producer.id_program = program.id_program
          LEFT JOIN producers
             ON producers.id_producer = program_producer.id_producer
          LEFT JOIN genres
             ON program.p_genre = genres.id_genre
          LEFT JOIN xcountries
             ON program.p_country = xcountries.id_country
          LEFT JOIN channels
             ON program.p_channel = channels.id_channel
GROUP BY program.id_program,
          program.original_title,
          genres.genre,
          genres.type_,
          program.director,
          program.origin1,
          program.broadcast_time,
          program.duration,
          channels.channel,
          program.local_title;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/619c34/1) showing the queries don't error; fix the partly-made up schema and add some data to check they get the results you expect.

Comment: The second solution looks so simple.. I don't know why I could see it, I guess the listagg thing lost me. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Since I'm not familiar on how to use WITHIN GROUP, could you please help me figure out how I could "order by producer.row_order" when "row_order" is not selected in the listagg function ?

Comment: @Marc - it doesn't need to be in the select list or group by clauses; you can just change it to `WITHIN GROUP (order by producers.row_order) AS producer`. Assuming that is actually a column name in that table, of course. Wonder if it's supposed to be the credited order or similar though, from `program_producers`.

Comment: I'm sorry again, I mixed it up, row_order was in the table program_producer and not in producer, therefore the correct syntax was "order by pp.row_order". Thanks a gain for your reactivity